# ERROR in config: /home/pi/catkin_ws/src has no workspace configuration file '.rosinstall'

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm running Indigo on a RPi

I have a code to run a servo as a ROS node. It has dependencies on sensor_msgs to use a PS3 controller. When I put ROS on the Pi, though, I used the bare bones install, no sensors. So, I tried to install it using

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sensor-msgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-sensor-msgs
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-common-msgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-common-msgs
```

I then read over the page on [ROS/Pi stuff](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi), and saw it said to make a new rosinstall file to download the packages. So I followed the instructions.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ rosinstall_generator common_msgs sensor_msgs --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ wstool merge -t src indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
ERROR in config: /home/pi/catkin_ws/src has no workspace configuration file '.rosinstall'
```

Now I don't know what to do. How can I not have rosinstall? I don't really know what's going on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202480/error-in-config:-/home/pi/catkin_ws/src-has-no-workspace-configuration-file-%27.rosinstall%27/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do `wstool merge -t src` then the `src` folder needs to have a `.rosinstall` file. You can get this by doing `wstool init src` first. Optionally you can do `wstool init src indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall` directly.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2015-02-09**:
Thank you, that was an easy fix.